# Is there a way to insert data to Oracle using Direct Path loading for in-memory records?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

New to Oracle here but I have now read about the various bulk insert options for Oracle. In essence, true bulk loading is done using Direct Path loading mechanism via SQL*Loader. There's also APPEND hint options that use serial or parallel Direct Path loading. But each of these have the following limitations -

1. SQL*Loader works off of a Control File, which contains the path of the data file. In my case, there is no file.
2. APPEND hint option for INSERT can only use the syntax - insert into select from. In my case, the source data is not in any table.

Source of my data is actually a Spark dataframe. I am looking for options to push this data in chunks to Oracle tables, but using Direct Path loading option. For example, in Postgres, the PGConnection interface provides getCopyAPI.copyIn functionality and you can create a huge serialized blob than can be sent over as one big chunk using COPY tableName FROM STDIN yourBlob command. I am unable to find anything similar Java API for Oracle that works on in-memory records and is able to push data directly (without any insert statements).

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Anyone done this before?
In general, how do folks using Oracle and Spark push data to Oracle from a dataframe in an optimized way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like asked too soon, it seems that folks are able to use sqlldr to take input from stdin - http://grokbase.com/t/freelists.org/oracle-l/0726h9kfz5/sqlldr-and-standard-input but still keeping it open to see if anyone has done this using Java/Scala (or any other language)

Comment: Also, can expdp and impdp be used instead of Sql*Loader? I believe these are only for importing / exporting database files and objects and may be not other files. But just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Interestingly, there's a .NET API for Bulk Load https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7287/what-specifically-does-oraclebulkcopy-do-and-how-can-i-optimize-its-performance, but no Java API?